# CRUD in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I'm trying Cassandra with simple CRUD operations and don't understand how should I model the data.

Let's say, we need to manage simple user data:

`UserId | Email | Name`

We want to be able to GET information by either `UserId` or `Email`. Also we want to be able to change user info, i.e. `Email` and `Name`.

That leads me to a dilemma: to query by `Email`, I should add it to PRIMARY KEY. But if I index it, I won't be able to UPDATE it.

How should I change the data model or indexing to be able to UPDATE the data?

From what I've read, secondary indexes are evil in Cassandra and I shouldn't use them to keep Cassandra's performance on a good level.

Comment: "secondary indexes are evil in Cassandra" - Love it!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you should not use secondary indexes unless you absolutely have to. But if you need to search by an email, you can create another table with 2 columns - `Email` and `UserId`. The primary key will be `Email` and that is how you will be searching for a `UserId` by `Email`. Think of it as of an index in a traditional relational database. Since the `Email` value should be unique - the lookup table approach should be more efficient than a secondary index.

Once you found `UserId` by `Email` you can use it in the queries to the main table.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I was thinking about the same solution, but the fact of multiple requests makes me uncertain in about that. Is it an "idiomatic" way to solve situation when you need to edit and search the same data or it's a workaround to particular task and I should better change the task itself (i.e. use events for CUD operations and aggregated data for reads)?

Comment: This approach is pretty typical in the Cassandra world. Yes, you will need to make several calls, but this is a little price to pay for not so typical situation in exchange for a very write-optimized system in general. I did mention traditional relational database indexes because they are using almost exactly the same approach - store the table's data almost as another table with the pointers to the main table's data in the lead level column.